# How to add resources from dependent project

Tags: java, eclipse, servlets

I've a Java project which has some resources located in a folder named *files* in the root of the project. When the project is running, this *files* folder is scanned for known resources. This is working fine when running this project on it own.

But I've a Web Project in Eclipse with a servlet. This web project has a dependency to the above java project. The project is added under *Java Build Path -> Projects*. But when running the above project from the servlet, the *files* folder does not exists. How can I add this folder from the dependent project to the web project?

Comment: Is the folder exported under the "Order and Export" tab of the build path dialog?

Comment: The *files* folder is not displayed in that tab for neither the java or web project.

Comment: That is going to be the problem then. When a project lists another as its dependency, it only refers to what's in the build path (classpath). You can't access regular files in the other project, only classes and resources via `getResourceAsStream()` calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If your dependent problem is added as *jar*, you can access it's resources via `ClassFromDependentProject.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(pathToResource)`. Eclipse will access resources from dependent projects directly, and in runtime they are available via jar.